# Sitecore - Field not detected as modified. How to force the save prompt to show?

Tags: javascript, c#, sitecore, taxonomy

We are using the Taxonomy module for Sitecore: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/T/Taxonomy.aspx?sc_lang=en

The module works fine 90% of the time. The only catch is  that when in a taxonomy field you select a value from the auto-complete options, the field doesn't seem to be marked as changed. This creates the occasional confusion with editors as when they publish the "Do you want to save?" prompt doesn't show and the content is published without tags.

If instead of selecting from the auto-complete we use the dialog box, everything works fine.

I looked at the markup, JavaScript and C# code and couldn't find a solution.
I even tried to set *Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Modified = true* but it doesn't seem to do anything.

**How can I force the save prompt to show?**

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I was updating a field using js and the experience editor wasnt detecting the change.

I got this working by doing the following using js:-

1. There is a save button state object saved in a view state field. You can grab by doing window.parent.document.getElementById("__SAVEBUTTONSTATE"). I then did the following:-

   ```
   var saveButtonState = window.parent.document.getElementById("__SAVEBUTTONSTATE");
   saveButtonState.value = 1;
   saveButtonState.onchange();
   ```

This will make the save button enabled

2. In the experience editor, Sitecore wraps your sitecore item fields in an span element, which contain a unique id. (These are the fields you interact with in the experience editor). However, its not these values which Sitecore receives when you hit Save button. Sitecore actually stores values of your item fields in hidden inputs, so when you interact with the span element, in the background, these hidden inputs are being updated. So in order for Sitecore to receive your changes, you must update the corresponding hidden input. If you open Inspect element in the experience editor and search "scFieldValues", you will see these hidden inputs. I updated the field by using jquery:-

   ```
   $('#scFieldValues').children('input').each(function () {
                       if (id.indexOf($(this).attr('id')) >= 0) {
                           $(this).val(value);
                       }
                   });
   ```

The id object is the id of the span element. The contents of that id is used in the id of the hidden input. This is why I use "id.IndexOf" to find correct input element. So when I update the span element value, I grab that value and update the corresponding input.

Hope this helps